# <ui:inputText/> and <lightning-input></lightning-input> onchange method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I'm a newbie in Aura Components and LWC. I was scrolling through the specifications <ui:inputText/> (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:inputText/specification) and <lightning-input></lightning-input> (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification) but I can not find the onchange or keyup methods, although they are being used as I found here for example:

```
<ui:inputText aura:id="lookup-field"class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-input-has-icon_left" 
updateOn="keyup"
value="{!v.searchText}"
keyup="{!c.onKeyUp}"
placeholder="{!'Search ' + v.objectLabelPlural + '...'}"
blur="{!c.onBlur}"
focus="{!c.onFocus}"
disabled = "{!v.disabled}"
/>
```

What is the reason behind the keyup or onchange event attributes missing in the specifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a note: ui components are deprecated. Do not use them in new code. Second, the documentation mostly only calls out events that are implemented as a CustomEvent dispatch. All standard DOM events are still triggered and still behave as normal, with the single difference being that target/currentTarget will be set to the closest Shadow DOM boundary to avoid leaking internal structures of components. DOM events otherwise behave exactly as you'd expect them to in plain HTML.

Comment: Okay, thanks sfdcfox